# WMI query for determining either the service is doing its work or not

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, wmi-query

I managed to query the httpd.exe service using WMI to check whether it is running or stopped. Here is the code that I am playing with:

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where Name='httpd.exe'"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
```

Now I would like to query the amount of CPU that the service is using. I want to know whether the running service is doing work or not. Can this be done? Am I asking the right question? need advice :)

Comment: is there a query that i can check the consumption of the particular service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Win32_Process`, You are able to get the `UserModeTime` and the `KernelModeTime` (given in 100 nanosecond units) which allows you to compute each CPU average during a certain time.

Assuming you get two `Win32_Process` informations separate by a `TimeInterval` (given in 100 nanosecond units).

```
UserTimeRate = ((UserModeTime2 - UserModeTime1) / TimeInterval) * 100;

KernelTimeRate =((KernelModeTime2 - KernelModeTime1) / TimeInterval) * 100;

CPU = (((UserModeTime2 - UserModeTime1) + (KernelModeTime2 - KernelModeTime1)) / TimeInterval) * 100;
```

If you want the rate from the begining, you can compute `TimeInterval` from  `CreationDate` to now.